# Leafletjs memory leak on map remove

Tags: memory-leaks, leaflet

I have developed a sample for a potential problem in `map.remove()`.

See: https://jsfiddle.net/moricio/e2wvwgu8/1/

This sample will choose a random lat/lng and will display a map centered at that point. It will wait 10 seconds before removing the map and generating a new position. It does this over and over.

If you open this sample in Chrome and check the Chrome task administrator(Shift-Esc) you will notice at each remove/add pair that the memory used by the tab will increase until your system crawls after a few hours.

Bug or my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in Leaflet - see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5263 and https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/5265 . Before that change, any `L.Canvas` or `L.SVG` (including the default one) were leaking quite a lot of memory. In Leaflet releases after that change, you should only experience a leak in one (hard to locate) circular reference to an instance of `L.Draggable`, which shouldn't be a big problem.